# Playwright converts to Capitalized api keys values to simple

Tags: playwright

I'm sending a post request using playwright

```
const response = await request.post(path,{ headers: { 'Accept': apiHeaders().ACCEPT, 'Content-Type': apiHeaders().CONTENT_TYPE, 'X-OO-SERVLET-TOKEN': apiHeaders().X_OO_SERVLET_TOKEN }, data: JSON.stringify(orderData().TOMORROWDELIVERYDATE) });
```

but X-OO-SERVLET-TOKEN is converted to simple like below in the request:

POST [https:/localhost/api/order]
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
content-type: application/json
x-oo-servlet-token: 680242a2a4d811a8a54eb6c6f33a
content-length: 444

expected should be in the request

POST [https:/localhost/api/order]
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
content-type: application/json
X-OO-SERVLET-TOKEN: 680242a2a4d811a8a54eb6c6f33a
content-length: 444

Answer (score 0):

Header names are not case sensitive, and converted to lowercase by default

```
8.1.2.  HTTP Header Fields

   HTTP header fields carry information as a series of key-value pairs.
   For a listing of registered HTTP headers, see the "Message Header
   Field" registry maintained at <https://www.iana.org/assignments/
   message-headers>.

   Just as in HTTP/1.x, header field names are strings of ASCII
   characters that are compared in a case-insensitive fashion.  However,
   header field names MUST be converted to lowercase prior to their
   encoding in HTTP/2.  A request or response containing uppercase
   header field names MUST be treated as malformed (Section 8.1.2.6).
```

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2

Comment: Thank you so much for the response https://stackoverflow.com/users/4170608/unickq